# InstanceID.getToken spontaneously started returning the app's name instead of a token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app used to give me a token, using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    try {
        String token = instanceID.getToken("28REDACTED98", GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "token: " + token);
```

This code has not been changed.  It used to produce a very long alpha-numeric token.

Now, it just returns my app name of `com.example.myapp` instead of a token.

I have tried reverting to previous version of code (which used to work) and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Wow, quite a strange bug. I've looked at my code and found 100% similarity between it and your code. Good thing you've fixed it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around - manually uninstalling the app from the phone, and re-installing, fixes the issue for a while.

Comment: Interesting. Did it only happen on a single device?

Comment: Yes, I only have a single device.

Comment: I see. I thought you were testing this with multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to ***migrate to Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM).***

It is the new version of GCM.

It is recommended to use FCM.

For migrating from GCM to FCM, just check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

and

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm

Comment: FCM is not quite ready yet - it needs Android Studio 2.2 which is not yet stable.

Comment: @chrisdew who told you that? Its not true

Comment: FCM and Android Studio are currently stable. You check again.

Comment: Hi @Saini, I think it would help chrisdew better if you can expound as to how migrating to FCM would help him fix the issue. *In FCM you will not face this issue **probably**.* doesn't really provide an answer.

Comment: @Saini - Sorry, I'm sure you can get it to work, but I didn't like the idea of trying something with warnings https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup or using the preview Android Studio 2.2. https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest (Note: these links will be show everything is fine, in a few weeks, but that was not the case on 2016-07-08.)

Comment: I am using firebase in Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: if you need more info, then you can study the firebase-messaging project at Github